# FLutter - How to dispatch an event on BLoC initialization

Tags: events, flutter, initialization, bloc

I know how you can set the initial state of a bloc easily. Is it possible to dispatch an event when a new bloc is created?

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  MyBloc() :
    this.dispatch(MyEvent()), // this line doesn't work
    super();

  @override
  MyState get initialState => MyStateInitial();

  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    if (event is MyEvent) {
      ... do some stuff here ...
      yield MyStateAfterMyEvent(someParameters, thatCantBe, setManually);
    }
  }
}
```

I know passing parameters to the bloc constructor could work sometimes. In my case parameters are fetched from the internet so I need more dynamic option. What is the way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the cascade operator `..` and a ' `factory` constructor.

```
factory MyBloc.dispatch(() => MyBloc()..dispatch(MyEvent());
```